# UnicodeDecodeError When Opening a tar File in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tar, python-unicode

I'm using Linux Mint 18.1 and Python 3.5.2.

I have a library that currently works using Python 2.7.  I need to use the library for a Python 3 project.  I'm updating it and have run into a unicode problem that I can't seem to fix.

First, a file is created via `tar cvjf tarfile.tbz2` (on a Linux system) and is later opened in the Python library as `open(tarfile)`.

If I run the code as is, using Python 3, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

My first attempt at a fix was to open it as `open(tarfile, encoding='utf-8')` as I was under the impression that tar would just use what the file system gave it.  When I do this, I get the same error (the byte value changes).

If I try with another encoding, say `latin-1`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Which leads me to believe that `utf-8` is correct, but I might be misunderstanding.

Can anyone provide suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I was going down the wrong path thinking this was some strange encoding problem.  When it was just a simple problem with that fact that `open()` defaults to read as text (`r`).  In Python 2 it's a no-op.

The fix is to `open(tarfile, 'rb')`.

The head fake with unicode...should have seen this one coming.  :facepalm: